# Typesafe curried pluck() and pick() in Typescript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm trying to write type-safe curried versions of `pick()` and `pluck()`, such that the functions first receive a list of properties and then an object that they act on. I can't figure out how to get the output types to be correct though. Here's where I got so far:

```
export const pick =
  <K extends string[], T extends Record<K[number], any>>(...props: K) =>
  (obj: T) => {
    return props.reduce((result: Partial<T>, nextKey: K[number]) => {
      if (nextKey in obj) result[nextKey] = obj[nextKey];
      return result;
    }, {});
  };

export const pluck =
  <K extends string[], T extends Record<K[number], any>>(...props: K) =>
  (obj: T) =>
    props.reduce((result, nextKey: K[number]) => result[nextKey], obj);
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1AYAw) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

`pick` is fairly easy to define since `Pick` already exists as a built-in utility:

```
declare function pick<K extends string[]>(...args: K): <T extends Record<K[number], any>>(obj: T) => Pick<T, K[number]>;
```

However, `pluck` takes a bit more work because we'd need to make the type ourselves.

Given something like `["a", "b", "c"]`, we want to construct a type

```
{ a: { b: { c: any } } }
```

which we can do succinctly using a recursive type and `Record`:

```
type Scoped<K extends string[]> = K extends [infer Head extends string, ...infer Tail extends string[]] ? Record<Head, Scoped<Tail>> : any;
```

If there no was input (base case for recursion as well), then it should just be `any`.

Next we need a type to actually do the plucking. Conveniently, since we already have a type that constructs the object out of the given props, this type is also very compact:

```
type Pluck<T extends Scoped<K>, K extends string[]> = K extends [infer Head extends string, ...infer Tail extends string[]] ? Pluck<T[Head], Tail> : T;
```

Then one could use these utilities in the definition of `pluck` like so:

```
declare function pluck<K extends string[]>(...args: K): <T extends Scoped<K>>(obj: T) => Pluck<T, K>;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1AYAw)

---

One drawback to this approach with currying is that you won't get any intellisense at the initial call...

Comment: Technically there is a way, but without partial generics it's a little verbose https://tsplay.dev/mAdRvN (it's also a little expensive)

Comment: @geoffrey Oh well yeah it is if you are able to pass in a type to work from. WIthout one then it's not.

Comment: I thought it was a bit "unfair" to list as a downside the lack of intellisence for,something that a non-curried API would not even be able to do. When you partially apply a path, you have some model at the back of your mind which corresponds to something. And that thing has a type. I really wish that extra `()` wasn't necessary though